# Compiling a static library which never gets changed

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I almost tryied everything.

I have a projet that use its own library. It's an old library, my colleague created 1 year ago.

This library is generated with a universal target as describe [this site](http://www.pixiapps.com/blog/?p=116).

When I compile the library, xCode create the .a files.

But when I try the lib in the enclosing project, it **never** gets refreshed.

I've cleared everything : the .a file my target build. The project build folder in DerivedData. The app in the device/simulator.

Each time the same old Log appears in the console, which I've removed (the workspace search of this log return nothing).

So, where the hell could be the f** cache xCode is always taking for creating this library ?

(Sorry for the nervousness, but I'm on it since 10am). Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is no cache for the library. Check the library search path within your project.

Comment: ... well done. There was an old library search path pointing on an old .a. How come din't I think about that?

Comment: I ve added my comment as an answer - feel free to either remove your question or accept my answer to prevent open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cache for the library. Check the library search path within your project.

[image]

Make sure you double-check if Project and Target use the same settings. Note that Target overwrites Project but Target also inherits Project if Target specifics are not written in bold letters (bold = overwriting).